# How to override <struts:text name="..."/> (Struts 2 Text jsp tag) to print out the name attribute in an HTML comment?

Tags: java, templates, text, struts2, jsp-tags

When you use a `<struts:text name="..."/>` Struts 2 Text jsp tag, you get a text from a .properties file in the page.

For example, if the .properties-file contains

```
foo.bar = This is the text.
```

The jsp tag `<struts:text name="foo.bar"/>` will output

```
This is the text.
```

Now i would like for all instances of `<struts:text name="...">` in the webapp to also output the name attribute inside an HTML comment, like so:

```
<!-- foo.bar -->This is the text.
```

I tried creating my own jsp tag file (to use instead of `<struts:text>`) that contained

```
<%@attribute name="name" required="true"%>

<!-- ${name} --><struts:text name="${name}"/>
```

but it doesn't work because `<rtexprvalue>` is set to `false` for the `name` attribute of the `struts:text` tag.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: `foo.bar = <!-- foo.bar -->This is the text.`?

Comment: @Ischin: `foo.bar` is just an example. I want it to work the same for all the hundreds of texts in the .properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# PROPERTIES
copyright.year=2011
```

**(B) : Override default theme** ([**is acceptable**](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/performance-tuning.html))

**label.ftl**

Add following code `<!-- ${parameters.name?html} -->`

```
<!-- ${parameters.name?html} -->

<label<#rt/>
...
</label>
```

**.jsp**

```
<s:label key="copyright.year" />
```

**HTML output :**

```
2011
```

**HTML source :**

```
<!-- copyright.year -->
<label id="form_name_copyright_year">2011</label>
```

---

**OR (not recommend)**

**label.ftl** with only 4 lines of code

```
<#if parameters.nameValue??>
<!-- ${parameters.name?html} --><#rt/>
<@s.property value="parameters.nameValue"/><#t/>
</#if>
```

**HTML source :**

```
<!-- copyright.year -->2011
```

---

**<strike>(A)</strike>**

```
/**
 * Overridden/replacement for {@link ActionSupport}.
 */
public class MyActionSupport extends ActionSupport {

    public String text(String fieldName) {
        return "<!-- " + fieldName + " --> " + getText(fieldName);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyAction extends MyActionSupport {

}
```

**.jsp**

```
<s:property value="text('copyright.year')" escapeHtml="false" />
```

**HTML output :**

```
2011
```

**HTML source :**

```
<!-- copyright.year --> 2011
```

Comment: Thank you, this should work, although i'm not too keen on duplicating `text('...')` and `escapeHtml="false"` on all tags. I would really like to have a tag of just the format `<x:text name="..."/>`

Comment: @Ischin: Sadly, `<struts:text/>` is not an UI tag, and thus it has no template and is not themeable.

Comment: @Christoffer Yes. See my updated answer **[(B)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307453/how-to-override-strutstext-name-struts-2-text-jsp-tag-to-print-out-th/6352481#6352481)**. You may override other unimportant tag, like `label`, `div`, ...

Comment: @Ischin: Thanks again! Why is the second one not recommended? Looks close to what i want.

Comment: @Christoffer Some other attributes (in `label.ftl`) will lose effectiveness, but it's not a big deal if `<s:label />` never use for other purposes.